# What is the proper way of operator overloading and why this is not working?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the `=, + +=` operators and the first two worked fine but the `operator+=()` function is producing an error.
Here is the code for the three:

**Overloading '=' operator**

```
inline vec3& operator = (vec3& ob) { 
    mX = ob.getX();
    mY = ob.getY();
    mZ = ob.getZ();

    return *this;
}
```

**Overloading '+' operator**

```
vec3 vec3::operator + (const vec3& ob) {
    vec3 vec(mX + ob.getX(), mY + ob.getY(), mZ + ob.getZ());
    return vec;
}
```

**Overloading '+=' operator**

```
vec3& vec3::operator += (const vec3& obj) {
    *this = *this + obj;
    return *this;
}
```

**Error**

`binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'vec3'`

Comment: The operators are usually implemented in the other order; `+` in terms of `+=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment operator should be const:

```
vec3& operator= (const vec3& ob)
```

Comment: Great! that helped. But why didn't it work in the previous case ?

Comment: Without the `const`, the RHS has to be a lvalue.

Comment: Yea but that is what I am asking. How does the `const` change it to rvalue ? @Eljay

Comment: `const&` can be used on temporary objects to extend their lifetime. There are plenty of questions on SO about this effect.

Comment: If you have a `vec3 const&` parameter, it can take an rvalue or lvalue argument.  If you have a `vec3&` parameter, it can only take a lvalue argument.  Adding the `const` does not change the argument to an rvalue.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. What I meant was that I just read an SO QA where it said that `vec3& operator= (const vec3& ob)` can be used on rvalue objects like `(a = b+c)` whereas `vec3& operator= (vec3& ob)` wont work. So my question is what is the `const` keyword doing internally, which triggers this behavior ? @MatthieuBrucher

Comment: As @Eljay said, it doesn't do anything, it can capture both rvalues and lvalues (because it's const).

Comment: why doesn't the non-const (`vec& operator = (vec3& ob)`) capture the rvalues ?

Comment: Because it's not `const`. Say you have `foo(int& i)`, you don't expect it to capture `foo(0)`. But `foo(const int& i)` will. As I've said, plenty of questions with great answers about this.

Comment: Finally! An answer that simple and clear cleared away all the blockage in my head. Huge thumbs up dude ;)